# how can I shuffle a list using a monad?

Tags: haskell

I have these data types:

```
data Card = Card One | Card Two | ...
data Deck = Deck [Card]
```

I want to shuffle the list cards in a deck

Here's where I am so far:

```
import System.Random

shuffle :: Deck -> Deck
shuffle (Deck c) = Deck $ shuffleOnce randomN c
    where   randomN = randomIO >>= (\x -> return (x `mod` 52))
            shuffleOnce n c = (findNth n c : deleteNth n c)
            findNth 0 (x:_) = x
            findNth n (_:xs) = findNth (n-1) xs
            deleteNth 0 (_:xs) = xs
            deleteNth n (x:xs) = x : (deleteNth (n-1) xs)
```

The problem (obviously) is here:

```
        where   randomN = randomIO >>= (\x -> return (x `mod` 52))
```

I have no idea how to use the `IO` monad to generate a random number. Once I wrap the random number from ` to 52 in the monadic context, how do I get it out?

Or better question, how do I actually shuffle the deck?

Please help. full code [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/94w46f/wrote_a_poker_solver_in_haskell/)

Comment: `shuffle :: Deck -> Deck` states that `shuffle` is a function from decks to decks, so it will produce the same output deck when given the same input deck. You want `shuffle :: Deck -> IO Deck` and then probably use `do` (or `>>=`, but it could be less convenient) to sequence the side effects. I'd recommend a monad tutorial.

Comment: recommending a tutorial isnt really helpful. also, i need to return a deck from the function, not an `IO Deck`.

Comment: You can't return a deck in Haskell and have it random. Haskell functions are functions -- same input, same output. If you want to use `randomIO` there's no way but to return `IO Deck`. This is a main design feature of Haskell, forcing the programmer to mark "impure" functions as such, by wrapping the result in the `IO` monad. To use randomness, one either works with `IO`, or passes around the RNG seed (being very careful not to reuse it twice, otherwise the same "random" numbers will be used twice).

Comment: @chi, I would recommend using a [`MonadRandom`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadRandom-0.5.1.1/docs/Control-Monad-Random-Class.html) constraint or similar. That'll work with `IO` and also with `RandT`.

Comment: @dopatraman "recommending a tutorial isnt really helpful. also, i need to return a deck from the function, not an IO Deck" A tutorial would explain why this is impossible without returning an `IO Deck` (or at least, without taking a random seed/sequence as a parameter).

Comment: Fair, what i meant to say was "recommending a tutorial without a link" isnt helpful. Which tutorial should i read / watch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiler said, that the problem is in `(randomN 1)`. `randomN` function is called with an argument, but it doesn't accept one.

Then it couldn't figure out, which type of random number is expected, so we need to provide one here:

```
randomIO >>= (\x -> return (x `mod` 52)) :: IO Int
```

Then `No instance for (Eq (IO Int))` error is received, which actually means, that `Int` is expected, but `IO Int` is provided. For convenience, we can swap the arguments of `shuffleOnce n c` and call this function as:

```
shuffleOnce c <$> randomN
```

After that, the error says:

```
Expected type: [Card]
Actual type: IO [Card]
```

We need to use `<$>` again instead of `$`, just to get "inside" `IO`:

```
Deck <$> shuffleOnce c <$> randomN
```

As a result, we receive:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘Deck’ with actual type ‘IO Deck’
```

We can't do anything about it, but change the type of `shuffle` function:

```
shuffle :: Deck -> IO Deck
shuffle (Deck c) = Deck <$> shuffleOnce c <$> randomN
    where   randomN = randomIO >>= (\x -> return (x `mod` 52)) :: IO Int
            shuffleOnce c n = (findNth n c : deleteNth n c)
            findNth 0 (x:_) = x
            findNth n (_:xs) = findNth (n-1) xs
            deleteNth 0 (_:xs) = xs
            deleteNth n (x:xs) = x : (deleteNth (n-1) xs)
```

Then we realise, that `shuffle` is a function with side effects, because it contains random numbers, which are "received from outside world". And actually having this information in the type definition seems logical.